# getServerSideProps not fetching data despite of running it inside the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch-api

hello i am trying to fetch data inside by next app using getServerSideProps which is just not fetching the data , the data returns either an empty object or undefined inside the console  i don't know what is wrong with the app , i have tried other next js data-fetching methods too and results are same

```
   export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
        // Fetch data from external API
        const res = await fetch(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character`)
        const data = await res.json()
        console.log(data)
        // Pass data to the page via props
        return { props: { data } }  
 }
```

Comment: Is the log of data present on the server side? Can we see the implementation of the page that accepts these props?

Comment: yes sure the complete code is here https://pastebin.com/zw2HA1Wf

Comment: `Product` needs to be a page component, which means it needs to be under the `pages` folder and you have to access it directly. If you use it inside another page component its `getServerSideProps` will not be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

I threw that code into my current project and it works.

```
interface Props {
  data: {
    info: any;
    results: any[];
  }
}

const Page: NextPage<Props> = ({ data }) => { 
  console.log(data); // { info: {...}, results: Array(20)}

  // ...
}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character');
  const data = await res.json();

  return { props: { data } };
};
```

Comment: how ? it is not working in my machine , what can be the reason , is something wrong with my installation of next js ?

Comment: First tell me if you can even see the data in the console on the server side. I'm using `"next": "12.1.2"` in my repo but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: no on the server side it returns a pair of empty brackets  '{}' and on the browser's console it return a object which have "[[Prototype]]: Object" inside  , link to full page code : pastebin.com/zw2HA1Wf also i am running the latest next 13

Comment: Then there's an error on the server side - for some reason you are not able to fetch the data from the API you are using. The code itself is fine. Try accessing the API in the browser/Postman and see what happens.

Comment: the api is running fine in browser